# How to convert specific string to split "=" for the key and value and convert it into json in golang

Tags: go

how to convert this kind of string to json like this (golang)

```
string:
 'abc=123
fruit=apple
pet=dog'


json:
{"abc":123,"fruit":"apple","pet":"dog"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by splitting the input string into individual lines (`entries`).
Then in a for loop, split each line on the `=` character and put an entry with respective key and value into the map (`m`).
You can then use `json.Marshall` to convert the map to json (`jsonString`).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
    s := `abc=123
fruit=apple
pet=dog`

    entries := strings.Split(s, "\n")
    m := make(map[string]string)
    for _, e := range entries {
            parts := strings.Split(e, "=")
        m[parts[0]] = parts[1]
    }
    jsonString, _ := json.Marshal(m)
    fmt.Println(string(jsonString))
}
```

Comment: @user14307253 please accept the answer if it satisfies your question - so it gets closed out.